# How to search in a List of Object that the Object's attribute contains a string

Tags: java, android, caching

I have a case of following:

- I have an object called `Song` with one of its attribute is `Name`.
- I have a sqlite database that can contain the Song up to million records.
- I need to do a live search (upon user tapping a letter, the app will directly search it) for the Song's Name attribute.

The solution that I've been thinking (I haven't done any code) is:

1. Directly querying the sqlite (I believe this is the worst solution because I need to fetch from sqlite and put it to `Cursor`)
2. Put all the sqlite records to List or ArrayList, then I'm not sure where to proceed as I believe to do for loop is not the best solution as I need to store to other List to prepopulate my `ListView`

Can anyone give me the idea, maybe the concept only, to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should do **caching** for your queries. Build an in-memory data structure for this, with a cascading structure (one letter at a time).

**Limit the number of the returned objects** (e.g. return max 10) for a specific query. Obviously you don't want want to return all `Song`s that begin with letter `A`. Also, this list may be based on importance (or selection frequency) - you can store that as well.

For the internal representation of the cache I recommend something like this:

```
public class SongCacheNode {
    private String selector;
    private Map<Character, SongCacheNode> subCaches = 
        new HashMap<Character, SongCacheNode>();
    private List<Song> selection = new ArrayList<Song>(10);
    private boolean leafNode = false;
    private boolean containsAll = false;
}
```

You can build a tree-like structure of this.

- The `selector` would store the string selector of this node (e.g. prefix of the song title).
- The `subCaches` can store the next cache for the next letter.
- The `selection` can store the picked song titles
- The `leafNode` would say that there are no more data stored in cache, you can either use `selection`, or you have to do `SQL` - that's stored in `containsAll`
- if `containsAll` is true, then all the possible songs are stored in `selection`, if not, you have to still do SQL

This structure allows you to build a **variable-depth cache**, depending the song title distribution. Also, for the selection **you can select any match**, not only the prefix match (e.g. many song title begin with 'The'), make a case-insensitive query, etc. You can do **partial caching** as well, to limit memory usage (e.g. to store maximum 5 characters, or do not store infrequent queries even with large number of songs) - just set `containsAll` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL lite allows [full text search functionality](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html). Given that song names can also be searched with partial terms like 'thrill' | 'thriller' | 'thriller MJ', you should go with that.

While the **full text search** would be indexed, depending on the load it might be too much for the DB to take, in which case you can build a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of song names. All matching songs can be obtained from the child nodes of the last matching node and this structure would be in memory. That should make it fast.

Loading song details into a list / set will not help since you cannot make partial matches. List / Set either contains 'thril' or it does not. There is no way to know if the partial string matches something in your DB unless you use full text search or an in-memory DS like a **trie**.

Answer (score 0):

**Your Options**  
By loading all the Songs into a list, you will speed up searching time. However, this will impact massively on loading time.

If you do not load all of the songs into the program, then you will have a much shorter loading time, but presumably longer searching lag.

**Which One I would go for**

Simply, I would choose the latter. The advantage here is that you can make the database call in another thread, while the user is typing. Multi-threading your application means that one the one thread, the user can happily type away, while on the other thread, the arduous database calls will occur, and the data can be loaded in.

**Some things to watch out for / Ideas you might want to use.**

If your database has a million songs, it's safe to say there will be alot of songs that start with the same letter. Perhaps not making a database call on the first few key presses will serve to your advantage for a number of reasons:

1. You will not have reams and reams of data coming in after every key press.
2. It will lessen the amount of data your program has to handle, thus lowering the performance hit.
3. This will provide a less intimidating user interface for the client. Imagine typing in a song and seeing a list of a hundred thousand songs come out of nowhere. It doesn't make for fluid usability.

Another idea is to cache the data, on each query. With this in mind, the same data can be obtained very quickly.